# Calculation of $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I want to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}$$

I tried integration by parts, $u = \arctan x$ that leads to $\int_0^{\arctan \pi/2} \dfrac{du}{1+\tan(\tan u)}$, but nothing seems to work...

Comment: I would use $x=arctan(u) $

Comment: I'd bet good money that it's supposed to be $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan^{-1} x)}$$instead.

Comment: @user790072 I'll bet good money that you are right. Even wolfram alpha can't work it out  (although I don't have pro computational time but still wolfram alpha can't find anything)